# Run .env file in django app with python-dotenv when starting shell

Tags: python, django, environment-variables, dotenv

I'm trying to use [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) to run the `.env` file when running `./manage.py shell`.

But `.env` isn't run when I start shell. Nothing different than normal happens.

**What I've done:**

1. installed `python-dotenv` with `pip install python-dotenv` in my virtual environment
2. added a `.env` file in the same directory as my project `settings.py`

Also added below to `settings.py`:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

For context, my `.env` looks like:

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=`pwd`/.pythonrc.py
echo "environment variables set"
```

And I'm exporting `.pythonrc.py` so I can do some imports when shell is loaded.

I'm pretty new to django. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you treat the env file as a shell one.

python-dotenv readme states that you can use `export` in your `.env` file, which is ignored by the package. This so that the env vars could alternatively be set by calling `source .env` from shell.

However, you can't run shell scripts that way. When I tried to load your example, I got this message:

```
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 2
True
```

After removing the `echo` line, I got just `True` as a response and `PYTHONSTARTUP` was set.

There's another issue, however, as you depend on shell scripting in the value of `PYTHONSTARTUP` as well. It's set to

```
'PYTHONSTARTUP': '`pwd`/.pythonrc.py'
```

Not what you'd expect. This should work:

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP2=${PWD}/.pythonrc.py
```